# Como posso fazer uma comparação do atributo?

Tags: php, yii

Como posso fazer a comparação >0 ou <0 entre estes atributos no Yii?

```
[
    'attribute' => 'gross_total',
    'header' => 'ENTRADAS'
],

[
    'attribute' => 'gross_total',
    'header' => 'SAÍDAS'
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que esteja utilizando um [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html) no Yii2. Na propriedade [value](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$value-detail) da `column`, você pode utilizar uma `closure` e efetuar a comparação:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'gross_total',
    'header' => 'SAÍDAS',
    'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        if($model->gross_total > 0){
            return 'Gross total maior que zero.'
        }
    }
],
```